# return to Index after delete

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

how can i return to index page, after delete item ?
i want close my partial view (modal) after delete and back to index page

```
    [BindProperty]
    public ItemDto Item{ get; set; } = new ItemDto();
    public PartialViewResult OnGetDelete(int id)
    {
        Invoice = _ItemApplication.GetDetails(id);
        return Partial("Delete", Item);
    }
    public JsonResult OnPostDelete(int id)
    {
        _ItemApplication.Delete(id);
         return new JsonResult(new { status = true, message = "Done!" });

    }
```

Comment: Have your tried  `return RedirectToPage("XXXXX");`?

Comment: @XinranShen `return RedirectToPage("XXXXX");` will not work because it's a `ajax` request always end up executing `success:function`. We either use asp.net core rzaor pattern to make it `return RedirectToPage("XXXXX");` work other than return `json result`, or use `window.location.href` inside ajax success function. This is the two way we have.

Comment: @Md Farid Uddin Kiron, I'm not sure If he need to do something else then redirect to index page in ajax success function or just redirect in backend. We need more details.

Comment: `JsonResult OnPostDelete(int id)` it means he is sending request from `ajax`, if you request from `ajax` control always goes back to `success:function` so you cannot use `RedirectToPage("XXXXX")` int backend, it will not work. You can try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can i return to index page, after delete item ? i want close my
> partial view (modal) after delete and back to index page

Well, as you are using `ajax`, you have to handle it within `success` and then redirect to your desired page using `window.location.href`. You can refer to below example:

**Solution:**

```
           $.ajax({
                url: "/Controller/OnPostDelete",
                type: "DELETE",
                data: {
                    'id': 1
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Index", "ControllerName")";
                    
                },
                error: function (xhr, error, thrown) {
                    alert("here2" + xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
```

**Full Demo:**

Delete Request Ajax:

```
        $.ajax({
                url: "/Controller/OnPostDelete",
                type: "DELETE",
                data: {
                    'id': 1
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);

                    window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Index", "Controller")?message=" + response.message;
                },
                error: function (xhr, error, thrown) {
                    alert("here2" + xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
```

Note: If you want to pass parameter to your `new redirected view` then you can use this way to pass parameter. If no parameter needed to pass then `"@Url.Action("Index", "ControllerName")";` is alright.

Delete Request Action:

```
[HttpDelete] 
public JsonResult OnPostDelete(int id)
    {
        _ItemApplication.Delete(id);
         return new JsonResult(new { status = true, message = "Done!" });

    }
```

Controller Need To Redirect:

```
public IActionResult Index(string message)
        {
            ViewBag.message = message;
            return View();
        }
```

View When Redirect:

```
<h1>The Redirect Value is: @ViewBag.message</h1>
```

Output:

[image]